# Call view from view on button click

Tags: codeigniter

i want call view from view. I guess that's possible but i don't know way to do that. I try something like this:

```
     <button id="submit-buttons" action="<?php  $this->load->view('some_view'); ?>​"​​​​​>Submit 1</button>
```

and doesn't work. Anyone have some idea?

Comment: and where do you want to call view? in a div inside view or popup etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply do it like this using jquery

View

```
<div id="result"></div> 
<button id="submit-buttons" href="#"​​​​​>Submit 1</button>
```

Also note button does not have action attribute

JQuery

```
$(function(){
    $('#submit-buttons').click(function(){
        $( "#result" ).load( "<?php echo site_url('controllername/methodname')?>" );
    })
})
```

Controller

```
function methodname(){
    $this->load->view('abc.php')
}
```

View will be loaded inside div having id `result`

Answer (score 1):

You working on MVC structure.So you should follow structure properly:
Your action should be a controller.From that you can call view.. 
Example:

```
<form method="" action="<?php  echo base_url(); ?>​controller_name/function_name">
       <button id="submit-buttons" type="submit" ​​​​​>Submit 1</button>
</form>
```

Controller:

```
function functionname(){
    $this->load->view('some_view')
}
```

Comment: he is working in button not form element. Button does not have action attribute